# Storing entire JSON object in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: javascript, java, json, postgresql, exception

I'm sending a JS object from my front-end to my Java backend, and I'm passing a object like so, which contains different types

```
wrapperObject = {
  JSONOBJ = {
      'key': 'value'
  },
  id: '123',
  date: 'exampledate'
}
```

My java backend then takes this wrapperObject and converts every field inside into a value inside of a hashmap Map. Whenever it reaches the JSONObject, however, it parses it and attempts to insert into the db and I reach a

`bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.`

What can I do about this, and is there a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it may be as simple as adding the [hstore extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html). The [PostgreSQL documentation for installation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.htm#AEN65382) looks pretty straightforward:

Let me know if I'm missing something, hope this helps!